# How to fix this NumPy loadtxt function?

Tags: python, pycharm

I am doing the following in PyCharm with NumPy.
I import NumPy, import an Excel file to PyCharm with 'numpy.loadtxt()', but it doesn't work:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

data=np.loadtxt('click.csv', delimiter=',', dtype='int', skiprows=1)

x_data=data[:,0]

y_data=data[:,0]

a=np.random.randint(0,10)

b=np.random.randint(0,100)

def f(x):
    return b+a*x

def E(x,y):
    return 0.5*np.sum((y-f(x))**2)

n=1e-3
D=1
count=0
error=E(x_data,y_data)


while D>1e-2:
    tmp0=b-n*np.sum((f(x_data)-y_data))
    tmp1=a-n*np.sum((f(x_data)-y_data)*x_data)
    b=tmp0
    a=tmp1
    current_error=E(x_data,y_data)
    D=error-current_error
    count=count+1
    if count%100==0 :
        print("Epoch:%.f,Rmse=%.04f,a=%.4f,yb=%.4f"%(count,E(x_data,y_data),a,b,))
```

The error is

`File "C:\Users\ss\Anaconda3\envs\tutorial\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\_datasource.py", line 624, in open 
raise IOError("%s not found." % path) OSError: click.csv not found.
Process finished with exit code 1.`

What does it mean?

Comment: There is no file click.csv in working directory

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the specific path to the csv file,
for example if the file is in C:\User\Files\clicks.csv, the correct command should be:

```
data = np.loadtxt('C:\User\Files\clicks.csv', delimiter=',', dtype='int', skiprows=1)
```

This should work